# Data frame couldn´t show

Tags: r

I try running the following code, but get error ar shown in the pictures below. Im quite new to R so dont know if its information to the case, but the first column in my data frame called "data" is dates. I get as.Dates.numeric(value) "origin" must be applied, my intuition says it got something to do with the date column, but then again, im a newbie. Just in case, the date column is not supposed to be a part of coef.vec.

```
v1 <- 2:7
coef.vec <- data.frame(NULL)           # create object to keep results
for (i in seq_along(v1)) {
  m <- summary(lm(data[,v1[i]] ~ data[,8]))    # run model
  coef.vec[i, 1] <- names(data)[v1[i]]           # print variable name
  coef.vec[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  coef.vec[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
  coef.vec[i, 4] <- mean(data[[i]])      # means of variables
  }

names(coef.vec) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x","variable.mean")
```

error1

[image]

error2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using `lapply` for column 2 to 7 of your data.

```
coef.vec <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(data)[2:7], function(x) {
                 m <- summary(lm(data[[x]] ~ data[[8]]))
                 data.frame(y.variable = x, 
                            intercept = m$coefficients[1,1],
                            coef.x = m$coefficients[2,1],
                            variable.mean = mean(data[[x]]))  
             }))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can construct the formula with `reformulate`, apply the `lm`, get the summary output with `tidy` from `broom` and create a single dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(names(data)[2:7], ~ 
     tidy(lm(reformulate(names(data)[8], response = .x), data = data)))
```

---

Or this can be done in a single step without any loop

```
 tidy(lm(cbind(iris[,1], iris[,2]) ~ Species, iris))
```

Or

```
tidy(lm(as.matrix(iris[1:2]) ~ Species, iris))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  response     term              estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#  <chr>        <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 Sepal.Length (Intercept)          5.01     0.0728     68.8  1.13e-113
#2 Sepal.Length Speciesversicolor    0.93     0.103       9.03 8.77e- 16
#3 Sepal.Length Speciesvirginica     1.58     0.103      15.4  2.21e- 32
#4 Sepal.Width  (Intercept)          3.43     0.0480     71.4  5.71e-116
#5 Sepal.Width  Speciesversicolor   -0.658    0.0679     -9.69 1.83e- 17
#6 Sepal.Width  Speciesvirginica    -0.454    0.0679     -6.68 4.54e- 10
```

and check the output from the loop

```
map_dfr(names(iris)[1:2], ~ tidy(lm(reformulate('Species', response = .x), data = iris)))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  term              estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)          5.01     0.0728     68.8  1.13e-113
#2 Speciesversicolor    0.93     0.103       9.03 8.77e- 16
#3 Speciesvirginica     1.58     0.103      15.4  2.21e- 32
#4 (Intercept)          3.43     0.0480     71.4  5.71e-116
#5 Speciesversicolor   -0.658    0.0679     -9.69 1.83e- 17
#6 Speciesvirginica    -0.454    0.0679     -6.68 4.54e- 10
```